# Why does my Data Layer Variable return the event name, instead of the value of the key given?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I want to use the value of the "user_id" field on my data layer in my Configuration Tag. 
So, I created a Data Layer Variable, which as the tooltip says, will receive exactly that: 
[image]

I have confirmed in Preview Mode, that the key on the dataLayer gets set correctly, and never overwritten: 
[image]

Under my GA4 Configuration Tag, in "Fields to set", I pass this Data Layer Variable 
for Google Analytics to receive it from Event Tags that use this configuration. 
("[Example 1: To set a user ID, add a row to Fields to Set. Set the Field Name to user_id, and the Value to a Tag Manager Variable that returns the user ID.](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/9442095)")
There, it is defined as a "User Property" by the same name ("user_id"),
which receives this value for reporting. 
(as instructed in the [best, and recent guide I found out there](https://ken-williams.com/guide/installation/properly-setting-the-user-id-to-track-activity-across-web-and-app-with-google-analytics-4/) ("Let's Set It Up", step 3.), although even that is already outdated (eg. "GA4 Configuration" is still called by its old name "Google Analytics: App+Web Configuration"), and doesn't reveal his DLV setup specifically...)
[image]
[image]

Yet in my Real Time view, under "users by users property", I end up seeing "gtm.js", ie. the name of the "Container Loaded" event which is set before the "user_id" field is pushed to the dataLayer (that's why you see it on the second screenshot): 
[image]

When I replace the Data Layer Variable in the configuration with a static value, 
that shows up in the Real Time view verbatim, so this DLV must be the culprit.
Is this a bug in my Data Layer Variable?

Answer (score 1):

So at long last it turned out,
that since the configuration tag was fired by the Page View event,
that happened before I pushed the user_id to the dataLayer,
and it filled the not-yet-existing value with the actual event name instead.

So I gave the user_id event a name to create a new custom event trigger,
that now re-triggers the configuration tag,
and this way the user_id-s are finally forwarded.